# How to assign hash['a']['b']= 'c' if hash['a'] doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby, hash, variable-assignment, autovivification, hash-of-hashes

Is there any way simpler than

```
if hash.key?('a')
  hash['a']['b'] = 'c' 
else  
  hash['a'] = {}
  hash['a']['b'] = 'c' 
end
```

Comment: Keywords: "ruby hash auto-vivification auto-vivifying" (let's see how SO links them in -- see "Related")

Comment: @pst: I think there was an edit conflict - someone fixed some typos and got rid of your tag.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest way is to [construct your Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a block argument:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }
hash['a']['b'] = 1
hash['a']['c'] = 1
hash['b']['c'] = 1
puts hash.inspect
# "{"a"=>{"b"=>1, "c"=>1}, "b"=>{"c"=>1}}"
```

This form for `new` creates a new empty Hash as the default value. You don't want this:

```
hash = Hash.new({ })
```

as that will use the **exact same** hash for all default entries.

Also, as Phrogz notes, you can make the auto-vivified hashes auto-vivify using [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc):

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

**UPDATE**: I think I should clarify my warning against `Hash.new({ })`. When you say this:

```
h = Hash.new({ })
```

That's pretty much like saying this:

```
h = Hash.new
h.default = { }
```

And then, when you access `h` to assign something as `h[:k][:m] = y`, it behaves as though you did this:

```
if(h.has_key?(:k))
    h[:k][:m] = y
else
    h.default[:m] = y
end
```

And then, if you `h[:k2][:n] = z`, you'll end up assigning `h.default[:n] = z`. Note that `h` still says that `h.has_key?(:k)` is false.

However, when you say this:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

Everything will work out okay because you will never modified `h[k]` in place here, you'll only read a value from `h` (which will use the default if necessary) or assign a new value to `h`.

Comment: As you know, but might want to point out, that only auto-vivifies one level deep, whereas doing this: `Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }` is turtles all the way down.

Comment: @mu: good explanation but I don't understand `that will use the exact same hash for all default entries.`. Don't we want default entries be the same?

Comment: @Radek: No, you don't want the default entries to be the same **object**. If they're using the same object then you'll end up with `hash['a']` and `hash['b']` being the same object and that won't even be in `hash` they way you want it to be. Try my example in `irb` but use the `Hash.new({})` constructor and you'll see the problem. The `Hash.new(x)` form only works sensibly when `x` is something like a Fixnum.

Comment: @Radek: And check `hash.inspect`, `hash.default.inspect`, `hash['a'].inspect`, and `hash['b'].inspect` after you run through the example with `Hash.new({})`.

Comment: @Radek: I added an update with a better explanation of why `Hash.new({})` is a bad idea.

Comment: Wikipedia shows a way to do this in a reusable fashion: `autovivify_hash_proc = proc { Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Array.new } }`. Then you just do `my_hash = autovivify_hash_proc.call`. Note that my example assumes that you want all vals to be `Array`s *source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Ruby*

Answer (score 10):

a simple one, but hash should be a valid hash object

```
(hash["a"] ||= {})['b'] = "c"
```

Comment: When compared to the use of a default proc this approach has a lot of flexibility.  To construct a default hash that sets `h[k]` to `{}` only when `k = 'a'`, one would write `Hash.new { |_,k| k=='a' ? {} : nil }`, which is pretty ugly. On the other hand, any or all of the strings in your expression could be variables, so it is in no way restrictive. Also, I've heard reports that this method tends to be faster than the use of a default proc. It's curious that `'b'` is in single quotes whereas,.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you create `hash` as the following, with default value of a new (identically default-valued) hash: (thanks to Phrogz for the correction; I had the syntax wrong)

```
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

Then you can do

```
hash["a"]["b"] = "c"
```

without any additional code.

Comment: Well, you can _do_ it, but your `hash` doesn't change. I think you meant:  `hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }`

Answer (score 0):

The question here: 
[Is auto-initialization of multi-dimensional hash array possible in Ruby, as it is in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148747/is-auto-initialization-of-multi-dimensional-hash-array-possible-in-ruby-as-it-i?lq=1)
provides a very useful `AutoHash` implementation that does this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NilClass
  def [](other)
    nil
  end
end
```

Once you defined that, everything will work automatically. But be aware that from now on `nil` would behave as an empty hash when used as a hash.