# PHP associative arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

In php i can do this:

```
$access = array();
$access['drivers']['create'] = 'administrator';
$access['drivers']['view']   = 'user';

echo $access['drivers']['view'];  # => 'user'
```

How can i do it in Ruby?

Comment: is it necessary to imperatively modify "access" or it can be defined in one step?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what resources have you been using to learn Ruby (apart from Stack Overflow)?

Comment: To learn Ruby i am doing web-project on ROR. Some answers i got from  _Programming Ruby 1.9_ book, some in google and some here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hash.

```
access = Hash.new # or {}
access["drivers"] = {}
access["drivers"]["view"] = 'user'
```

You can use an array as the key if you want.

```
access = Hash.new
access["drivers", "view"] = "user"
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

access = Hash.new
access['drivers'] = Hash.new
access['drivers']['create'] = 'administrator'
access['drivers']['view']   = 'user'

puts access['drivers']['view']  # => 'user'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's Worth Noting that the convention is often to use `:symbols` instead of `"strings"`

`access[:drivers][:view]`

they are basically just immutable strings. Since strings are mutable objects in Ruby, hashes convert them to immutable ones internally ( to a symbol no less ) but you can do it explicitly and it looks a little cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the block form of [`Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718) to provide an empty Hash as a default value:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { }; h[k].default_proc = h.default_proc; h[k] }
```

And then this happens:

```
>> h[:this][:that] = 6
# h = {:this=>{:that=>6}}
>> h[:other][:that] = 6
# {:this=>{:that=>6}, :other=>{:that=>6}}
>> h[:thing][:that] = 83724
# {:this=>{:that=>6}, :other=>{:that=>6}, :thing=>{:that=>83724}}
```

The funny looking [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000733) stuff in the block shares the main hash's default value generating block with the sub-hashes so that they auto-vivify too.

Also, make sure you don't do this:

```
h = Hash.new({ })
```

to supply a hash as a default value, there is some explanation of why not [over in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878529/how-to-assign-hashab-c-if-hasha-doesnt-exist/5878626#5878626).

Answer (score 0):

From the question is unclear if you really need to update the structure. I'd most write something like this:

```
access = {
  :drivers => {
    :create => "administrator",
    :view => "user",
  },
}

access[:drivers][:view] #=> 'user'
```