# Is there a way to initialize all child node of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

It's just redundant having to initialize the child element all the time. What I meant was this:

```
@parent = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

if I try to create another multi-dimensional node, I try coding:

```
@parent[:child][some_field] = "Some example data..."
```

I am always getting this error:

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This works for me: `parent = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) };
parent[:child][:some_field] = 4`. Can you give us more precise steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What do you have as `default_proc`?

Comment: What Ruby version do you use?

Comment: The constructor for the hash is correct, what I suspect is that something like `@parent[:child] = nil` happens somewhere in the code

Comment: I think you're right. The configurations are correct, and after a bit of testing, I found the culprit. It turns out that the @parent example above doesn't use the Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) } instead, an object from simple_xlsx_reader. The app I'm building is a generator, where if no parameters are found, will use the given example above.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878529/how-to-assign-hashab-c-if-hasha-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 3):

I you need nested hashes more offen, why don't you define your own class?

```
class NestedHash < Hash  
  def initialize
    super { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
  end
end

h = NestedHash.new
h[:foo][:bar] = :baz
h[:foo][:bar] #=> :baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat similar to spickermann's answer, but a little different.

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def initialize
    self.default_proc = proc{|h, k| h[k] = MyHash.new}
  end
end

@parent = MyHash.new
```

Note that there is no need to pass arguments/block to `MyHash.new` as setting a different default would defeat the purpose of using `MyHash`, and `Hash` would be better suited in such case.