# What are the equivalent to Lodash's get and set in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lodash

I would like to use something similar to Lodash's get and set, but in Ruby instead of JavaScript. I tried few searches but I can't find anything similar.

Lodash's documentation will probably explain it in a better way, but it's getting and setting a property from a string path ('x[0].y.z' for example). If the full path doesn't exist when setting a property, it is automatically created.

- [Lodash Set](https://lodash.com/docs#set)
- [Lodash Get](https://lodash.com/docs#get)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5878626/163640

Answer (score 2):

I eventually ported Lodash _.set and _.get from JavaScript to Ruby and [made a Gem](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.3 introduces the new safe navigator operator for getting nested/chained values:

```rb
x[0]&.y&.z #=> result or nil
```

Otherwise, Rails monkey patches all objects with `try(…)`, allowing you to:

```rb
x[0].try(:y).try(:z) #=> result or nil
```

Setting is a bit harder, and I'd recommend ensuring you have the final object before attempting to set a property, e.g.:

```rb
if obj = x[0]&.y&.z
  z.name = "Dr Robot"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. In my use case, the string path is dynamic and only known at runtime, but I will use the safe navigator operator in other places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rudash Gem that comes with most of the Lodash utilities, and not only the _.get and _.set.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have had the need to programmatically get the value for a property deep into an object, but the thing is that sometimes the property is really a method, and *sometimes* it needs parameters!

So I came up with this solution, hope it helps devising one for your problem:
(Needs Rails' #try)

```rb
def reduce_attributes_for( object, options )
  options.reduce( {} ) do |hash, ( attribute, methods )|
    hash[attribute] = methods.reduce( object ) { |a, e| a.try!(:send, *e) }
    hash
  end
end

# Usage example
o = Object.new

attribute_map = {
    # same as o.object_id
    id: [:object_id],
    # same as o.object_id.to_s
    id_as_string: [:object_id, :to_s],
    # same as o.object_id.to_s.length
    id_as_string_length: [:object_id, :to_s, :length],
    # I know, this one is a contrived example, but its purpose is
    # to illustrate how you would call methods with parameters
    # same as o.object_id.to_s.scan(/\d/)[1].to_i
    second_number_from_id: [:object_id, :to_s, [:scan, /\d/], [:[],1], :to_i]
}

reduce_attributes_for( o, attribute_map )
# {:id=>47295942175460,
#  :id_as_string=>"47295942175460",
#  :id_as_string_length=>14,
#  :second_number_from_id=>7}
```