# saving and fetching hash in Mongoid Document

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, mongoid

I am creating a metrics hash using the following:

```
@metrics = Hash.new

...

@metrics[:users][:year][:male] = ...
@metrics[:users][:today][:male] = ...

...

Metrics.new(:metrics => @metrics).save
```

and I have the following class:

```
class Metrics
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :metrics, :type => Hash

  attr_accessible :metrics

  ...

end
```

To fetch this document, I have:

```
@metrics = Metrics.find(params[:id])
@metrics = @metrics[:metrics]
```

In order to access these elements, I need to do:

```
@metrics['users']['year']['male']
```

Is there a way I can be consistent in how I access hash values but still storing data in mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ruby and Mongoid are you using? Accessing hashes in Mongoid objects via symbols works fine in Mongoid 3.0.4 and Ruby 1.9.3. So I can do something like:

```
@metrics = Metrics.find(params[:id])[:metrics]
@metrics[:users][:year][:male]
```

or even:

```
Metrics.find(params[:id])[:metrics][:users][:year][:male]
```

Also, why not just leave the `metrics` field out, then treat instances of the `Metrics` class like instances of `Hash`? With Mongoid you can dynamically set and get attributes using the standard Ruby Hash symbol syntax without ever "declaring" the fields. With the `metrics` field removed:

```
m = Metric.new
m[:users] = {}
m[:users][:year] = {}
m[:users][:year][:male] = "data"
```

Additionally, if you need methods to auto-initialize nested hashes, so you can do things like:

```
m = Metric.new
m[:users][:year][:male] = "data"
```

you can put all of that logic into the `Metrics` class. To get started on that you could try adapting something like the `[]` and `[]=` methods from the AutoHash class explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148747/is-auto-initialization-of-multi-dimensional-hash-array-possible-in-ruby-as-it-i). That would give you the cleanest interface I think.

Comment: hmm, I'm on Mongoid 2.4. I'll try upgrading and using this solution later today